# How is chicken egg a single cell

Tags: cell-biology

It is unexpected for ostrich or chicken egg to be single cell yet so large.

How could it happen, I thought egg is made up of several single cells.

If not, how is yolk a single cell http://www.alearned.com/egg/

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about this Stack Exchange.  At this SE, we like questions that show that the person asking has done some research for possible answers for themselves.

Answer (score -4):

Before the egg hatches, there is really only one intact cell inside the egg, that is the yolk. Before fertilization, the yolk is just an egg cell, but after fertilization, it is a fertilized egg. If the egg begins to hatch and the fertilized egg cells undergo cell division, there's not just one cell. A white spot on the surface of the yolk. The unfertilized egg is called an egg, and the fertilized egg is called a zygote, which further develops into an early blastocyst. The disc of the fertilized egg is about 3 mm in diameter, and the ovule of the unfertilized egg is smaller.

Comment: Welcome to the site, please visit the [help] to see what makes a good answer. In particular, this site (Biology SE) values answers that have some references to back them up.

Comment: But the yolk is too big for intracellular communication and exchange of mayerials @Jeffrey

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Hatching" refers to the process of the fully-developed chick (definitely a multicellular organism) exiting the egg casing. It only occurs at the very end of gestation.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. In particular, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Also note from [answer], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* This is an inappropriate (under researched) question (see help) — please delete your post to avoid encouraging such questions.